# One hot encoding from image labels using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have been puzzling over this one hot encoding problem. I am sure it is a simple process, but I have been looking at this problem for awhile and cannot see my mistake.

I have a set of train_labels of shape (1080,1), and there are 6 integer classes. I am trying to turn this into a one hot vector using the following:

```
def convert_to_one_hot(train_labels_conv,classes):
    Y_train = np.eye(classes)[train_labels_conv.reshape(-1)].T
    return Y_train

Y_train = np.arange(6)
print(Y_train)
Y_train_hot = convert_to_one_hot(Y_train, len(Y))
print(Y_train_hot)
```

```
As a result I simply get
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Should I not have received the whole one hot matrix for my training labels? I would appreciate any instruction in the right direction as I am not yet comfortable using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your labels are strings, you can use this function:

```py
import numpy as np

target = np.array(['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 
    'cat', 'cat', 'hamster', 'hamster'])

def one_hot(array):
    unique, inverse = np.unique(array, return_inverse=True)
    onehot = np.eye(unique.shape[0])[inverse]
    return onehot

print(one_hot(target))
```

> Out[9]:  
>   [[0., 1., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [0., 1., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [1., 0., 0.], 
>          [0., 0., 1.], 
>          [0., 0., 1.]])